# BMP в базе данных

Tags: mysql

Как сохранить BMP в базе Данных?

Answer (score 4):

Зачем хранить BMP в базе, если можно хранить в базе ссылку на BMP, а сам BMP хранить в каком-нибудь файловом хранилище? Например, DropBox.

Если вы скажите для каких целей вы собираетесь хранить файлы, то возможно люди подскажут вам более подходящий для вас вариант.

PS: Я надеюсь BMP - это все-таки картинка, а не что-то, что не успело прийти мне на ум.

Answer (score 0):

1. Переводите картинку в массив байтов.
2. Сохраняете массив байтов в базе данных.

Пример:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (IMAGE_BYTES) VALUES (@image_bytes)
```

где через параметр предаете в @image_bytes вашу картинку.

Comment: Для веба не предпочтительный вариант.